# L'Hopital rule application. Two examples.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln{x}}{x}$$

Can I use L'Hopital's rule here? This evaluates to $\frac{-\infty}{0}$. Can you use L'Hopital's rule in this case?

Also in this example, how do I simplify:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8^t - 5^t}{t}$$

$$ = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8^t \cdot \ln{8} - 5^t \cdot \ln{5}}{1}$$

Where do I go from here?

Is the derivative of $b^t$ (where b is a constant) = $b^t \cdot ln{b}$?

Comment: Please *limit* yourself to one question per post

Comment: Is the second limit ln8 - ln5?

Answer (score 1):

For $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln{x}}{x}$$ we can not use L'Hospital rule because it is not a $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

For $$   \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8^t - 5^t}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8^t \cdot \ln{8} - 5^t \cdot \ln{5}}{1}=\ln 8-\ln 5$$ seems right.